# d3 - how to format xAxis ticks depending on weeks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 time scale chart. At the moment, the axis ticks render a date for every data object. The data could have a range of anything from 1 day of data, or 2 weeks in 1 month, or 5 months worth of data or even more, for example.

Ideally, we want to display ticks with a week number, *based on the data* - **not** the week number of the year or month like this: `xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%W'))` Eg, if the data starts from 15th of July, the first tick would say 'week 1', then 'week 2', etc.

How could you achieve such axis ticks with a time based d3 line chart? I'm new to d3 and almost lost with how to achieve this.

I'm using moment.js as well, so inside `xAxis.tickFormat`, i've tried using a function with some logic that returns different values depending on the date, but this seems fragile and not 'the d3 way'. Also tried using a custom time formatter [as seen here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176).

Alternatively, we could have simpler ticks - just displaying the month and/or day with `d3.time.format(%d-%b)`, but then there are duplicate tick values like 'Feb...Feb..Feb..Feb...Feb..Mar..Mar..Mar..`. Is there a method to prevent duplicate values from appearing?

I've tried limiting the amount of ticks, but this isn't working as expected. Eg, If I have `xAxis.ticks(5)`, 3 ticks appear; same story if I have `xAxis.ticks(2)`. If ticks is defined as 1, only 1 tick appears. What's going on here?

Any help would be most appreciated! Code below with 2 dataset examples

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<style>
path { fill: #CCC; }
.line { fill: none; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 5px;}
</style>

<div id="chart-container">
    <svg id="chart"></svg>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var now = moment();
    var chartData = [
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(27, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 40 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(25, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(24, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(21, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(20, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(18, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(17, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(16, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(15, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 32 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(13, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(11, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 31 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(10, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 28 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(9, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 32 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(8, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 30 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(7, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(6, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 }
    ];


    //data could have a shorter date range of eg, 1 or 2 weeks
    //ideally we want to still display 'week 1, 2, 3, 4' etc in the axis.
    //alternatively display dates instead
    // var chartData = [
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(27, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 40 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(25, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(24, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(21, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(20, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 }
    // ];

    let lastObj = chartData[chartData.length - 1];
    let lastObjTimestamp =  lastObj.timestamp;
    let lastAndNow = moment(lastObjTimestamp).diff(now, 'days');
    console.log('difference between last entry ' + lastObjTimestamp  + ' and today: ' + lastAndNow);

    var chartWrapperDomId = 'chart-container';
    var chartDomId = 'chart';
    var chartWrapperWidth = document.getElementById(chartWrapperDomId).clientWidth;
    var margin = 40;
    var width = chartWrapperWidth - margin;
    var height = 500 - margin * 2;

    var xMin = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(chartData[0].timestamp);
    var xMax = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(chartData[chartData.length-1].timestamp);

    //set the scale for the x axis
    var xScale = d3.time.scale();
    xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);
    xScale.range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .nice();

    console.log('no5 ', chartData[5].timestamp)

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d-%b'));
        //.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b'))
        //tickFormat(d3.time.format('%W'));
        //.ticks(5);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left');

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return xScale(d.timestamp);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(d.value);
        });

    var svg = d3.select('#' + chartDomId)
        .attr('width', width + margin * 2)
        .attr('height', height + margin * 2)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ',' + margin + ')');

    chartData.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(d.timestamp);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    yScale.domain(d3.extent(chartData, function(d) {
        return d.value;
    }));

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
        .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    svg.append('path')
        .datum(chartData)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', line);

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the first weekday (eg. Wednesday) from your data and set ticks according to that.

It can be achived using the following code:

```
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0]=  'sunday';
weekday[1] = 'monday';
weekday[2] = 'tuesday';
weekday[3] = 'wednesday';
weekday[4] = 'thursday';
weekday[5] = 'friday';
weekday[6] = 'saturday';

var startDay = weekday[new Date(chartData[0].timestamp).getDay()];

var week = 1;
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickFormat(function() { return 'week ' + week++ })
    .ticks(d3.time[startDay]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>

<style>
path { fill: #CCC; }
.line { fill: none; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 5px;}
</style>

<div id="chart-container">
    <svg id="chart"></svg>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var now = moment();
    var chartData = [
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(27, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 40 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(25, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(24, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(21, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(20, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(18, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(17, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(16, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(15, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 32 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(13, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(11, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 31 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(10, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 28 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(9, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 32 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(8, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 30 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(7, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
        { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(6, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 }
    ];


    //data could have a shorter date range of eg, 1 or 2 weeks
    //ideally we want to still display 'week 1, 2, 3, 4' etc in the axis.
    //alternatively display dates instead
    // var chartData = [
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(27, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 40 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(25, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 36 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(24, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 33 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(21, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 },
    //     { timestamp: moment(now).subtract(20, 'days').format('DD-MMM-YY'), value: 35 }
    // ];

    let lastObj = chartData[chartData.length - 1];
    let lastObjTimestamp =  lastObj.timestamp;
    let lastAndNow = moment(lastObjTimestamp).diff(now, 'days');
    console.log('difference between last entry ' + lastObjTimestamp  + ' and today: ' + lastAndNow);

    var chartWrapperDomId = 'chart-container';
    var chartDomId = 'chart';
    var chartWrapperWidth = document.getElementById(chartWrapperDomId).clientWidth;
    var margin = 40;
    var width = chartWrapperWidth - margin;
    var height = 500 - margin * 2;

    var xMin = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(chartData[0].timestamp);
    var xMax = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(chartData[chartData.length-1].timestamp);

    //set the scale for the x axis
    var xScale = d3.time.scale();
    xScale.domain([xMin, xMax]);
    xScale.range([0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .nice();


    console.log('no5 ', chartData[5].timestamp)

    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  'sunday';
    weekday[1] = 'monday';
    weekday[2] = 'tuesday';
    weekday[3] = 'wednesday';
    weekday[4] = 'thursday';
    weekday[5] = 'friday';
    weekday[6] = 'saturday';

var startDay = weekday[new Date(chartData[0].timestamp).getDay()];

    var week = 1;
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        //.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%d-%b'));
        //.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%b'))
        //tickFormat(d3.time.format('%W'));
        .tickFormat(function() { return 'week ' + week++ })
        .ticks(d3.time[startDay]);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left');

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return xScale(d.timestamp);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return yScale(d.value);
        });

    var svg = d3.select('#' + chartDomId)
        .attr('width', width + margin * 2)
        .attr('height', height + margin * 2)
      .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ',' + margin + ')');

    chartData.forEach(function(d) {
        d.timestamp = d3.time.format('%d-%b-%y').parse(d.timestamp);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

    yScale.domain(d3.extent(chartData, function(d) {
        return d.value;
    }));

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y-axis')
        .call(yAxis)
    .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');

    svg.append('path')
        .datum(chartData)
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', line);

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you CuriousSuperhero! I didn't think the solution could be so clean and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Since in many cases d3 forces judgments on how many ticks to place along your axes regardless of how many you specify, this is how I went about defining the specific ticks that I wanted:

```
var tickLabels = ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5'];

d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues([0, 7, 14, 21, 28])
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      return tickLabels[i]
    });
```

.tickValues specifies the data points (aka dates) where I want my ticks to be placed, while tickFormat changes each of those respective numbers to "Week 1", "Week 2", etc.